# Facebook Javascript SDK - Is there a call back function once fb:likes have been loaded?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

I am wondering if it is possible to run some javascript once fb:like buttons have been loaded? 
In context: I am wanting to add a `.fbloaded` class to the body element to give greater control over the visual loading of the buttons.

I have ploughed through the API but to no avail.

Thanks for your time,
Ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to trigger a callback using FB.event.subscribe.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe

There are also a few examples of the code in action, with a like button here:

http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-capture-clicks-on-the-facebook-like-button/

Hope that helps!